# Cannot save associated model id in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I have set up models Producer and Product. When I want to create a new product, in the form I can choose Producers from list. Here is the code:

```
<%= select("producer", "producer_id", Producer.all.collect {|t| [ t.name, t.id ] }, {:prompt => 'Select producer'})%>
```

It works fine, but when I want to save the created product, it shows up that `producer_id` cannot be blank, which is caused by the validations I created. 
I have set column `producer_id` to Product table, created associations, everything what I was told.

Here is my code:

**Product Controller**

```
def new
@product = Product.new

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @product }
end 

def create
   @product = Product.new(params[:product])
end
```

**Product model**

```
belongs_to :producer
```

**Producer model**

```
has_many :products
```

I hope somebody can help!

Comment: `<%=select("producer", "producer_id", Producer.all.collect {|t| [ t.name, t.id ] }, {:prompt => 'Select producer'})%>` shouldn't the first parameter be `product` instead of `producer`?

Comment: @jvnill Yes, it should. But now it gives a error like `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id`

Comment: you are calling `nil.id` somewhere in your code. include the part of the code that causes this error in your question

Comment: @jvnill yea, it was in ProductsController where I had some interesting code :D I commented out , now it works !! Thank You!

Comment: `@product = Product.new(params[:product]) @product.save`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your controller you reference params[:product], but in your view you use "producer".  Change select("producer".. to select("product" and it will work fine.

```
def create
   @product = Product.new(params[:product])
end

<%= select("producer", "producer_id", Producer.all.collect {|t| [ t.name, t.id ] }, {:prompt => 'Select producer'})%>
```